# 'Manually release this version' - Apple App Store- iOS

Tags: ios, swift, build, app-store, release

Once I mark my iOS build to 'Manually release this version' on the app store and get Apple review done on the build, is it possible to withdraw the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When setting 'Manually release this version', in case you don't want to release it to the App Store, you can reject it even if it has passed the review.